# Usage of やばい and 危ない

Tags: usage, word-usage

As I know, Both words mean Dangerous. Japanese people use sometimes やばい, other times 危ない. When should I use one over other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While both,「危ない」and「やばい」mean dangerous, 「危ない」is more used in physical situation (It's 危ない to go on the street at red light) and「やばい」is more like "Because I didn't learn for the test it's really やばい".
Also やばい is a really common slang word for amazing, cool or awesome situations.

Answer (score 4):

Generally,「危ない」is physically dangerous, while 「やばい」 is mentally.

Answer (score 1):

「やばい」 commonly used meaning awesome by young people. やばい has many means.
（例）
この前見た映画、すごくやばかった。→great, amazing
これはやばいエラーだ。→awful
仕事の締め切りに間に合わなくてやばい。→dangerous
(It depends on the situation.)

Older people hate this 「やばい」usage.