# 単語 ヤバイ origin and comparaision

Tags: words

[image: where does this ヤバイcome from?tks] is there any other same words? i mean the origin of this word.

Comment: Related? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/54830/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/46797/9831 This might be of some help too: http://gogen-allguide.com/ya/yabai.html